# Variable not being set upon view transition

Tags: ios, tableview

Currently I have a table view controller and a custom table view cell. Upon creation, the first table view cell is of the class GroupHeader, and GroupHeader has a public groupID variable. However, when I create a GroupHeader cell, and set its groupID, it does not reflect this change in the cell class.

GroupTableViewController Class:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

tableView.allowsSelection = NO;
if(indexPath.section == 0){
    GroupHeader*cell = [[GroupHeader alloc] init];
    cell.groupID = groupID;
    NSLog(@"AAAAA %d",cell.groupID);
    [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"group_header"    forIndexPath:indexPath];

    return cell;
}}
```

GroupHeader Class:

```
-(void)awakeFromNib{
NSLog(@"BBBBB %d",groupID);}
```

In the log, AAAAA does come before BBBBB along with the correct groupID, but BBBBB comes with 0 instead of the correct groupID. I don't understand how this is possible.

What I am trying to achieve is that the groupID be passed to the cell so that I can do stuff with the groupID BEFORE the cell appears on the screen. However, when the cell is dequeued, it seems to automatically call the awakeFromNIB before the groupID has a chance to be passed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the identifier of the cell is properly set in Interface Builder, get the cell from `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier` and cast the object accordingly.

```
GroupHeader *cell = (GroupHeader *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"group_header" forIndexPath:indexPath];
cell.groupID = groupID;
NSLog(@"AAAAA %d",cell.groupID);
return cell;
```

Comment: Now, the BBB shows up(still incorrectly 0), while the AAA does not show up at all. I think with this solution it is creating the cell before you set the groupID, going backwards from what I am trying to achieve.

Comment: My dilemma I believe is that the moment I call dequeue, it calls the awakeFromNib function on the cell. However, I need to set its groupID before I call awakeFromNib.

Comment: Of course the variable is set after `awakeFromNib` is called. Add more information to your question what you're going to achieve.

Comment: I just did. Does that help?

Comment: Why do you want to do things before the cell appears? The human eyes are too slow to notice the difference.

Comment: By that I mean the cell is filled with data on the awakeFromNIB function, so I need to make sure groupID is set before the awakeFromNIB function is called.

Comment: Never mind, I got it to work by using a different function. Thank you!